# About Wireshark and http/tcp stream

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark

[image]

Anyone can tell me why I received HTTP 200 response before I send the request? So weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually GET request was sent in packet #747. You can catch it from the following facts:

- the size of the packet (628 bytes) - it's enough to send GET
- the response was received from the server.

This request doesn't have a body but it has `Content-Type` header. I guess because of that header Wireshark thinks that it's going to be a body and tries to wait it until packet #776. I've checked the similar scenario but without `Content-Type` header and Wireshark displays the request in a right place.

RFC says "The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in the request's message-headers." So there should not be a body. But as I know Wireshark serves for working even with not standard or well-implemented variants of protocols. So I think it is not a bug.

Comment: Perhaps the GET request didn't have a Content-Length header and Wireshark was waiting for the end of the connection (FIN) as an indication that the request was complete.  As the server obviously wasn't wanting for an end-of-connection indication, this is probably a Wireshark bug; Field.wei should file a bug at [the Wireshark Bugzilla](https://bugs.wireshark.org/) and attach the capture to the bug.

Comment: @GuyHarris GET request usually doesn't have a body and Content-Length header. I've just checked Chrome's request: no Content-Length but Wireshark displays it correctly before the response. Maybe that request from the question _has_ Content-Length !=0 but the server ignored it.

Comment: That's why I want a bug filed and a capture attached - so we can see why Wireshark thinks that some (re)assembly is required. :-)

Comment: @GuyHarris I have report a bug : https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11104

Comment: See my comments in [bug 11104](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11104).  Wireshark should probably treat GET requests that don't imply the presence of a message-body as not having a message-body rather than having one terminated by a FIN.

Comment: The blunt statement in section 4.3 is perhaps a bit softened by the stuff in section 4.4, or maybe the algorithm is "decide based on section 4.3 whether it even has a message-body and, if it does, determine the length based on section 4.4", so that even "Transfer-Encoding: identity" implies a message-body and a media type of multipart/byteranges without Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding implies *no* message-body.

Comment: And, given that the servers I've Telnetted into seem not to expect a message-body in GET requests if I specify neither Content-Length nor Transfer-Encoding, I'd say Wireshark should go with section 4.3, even if some clients don't get it right - most servers will probably get hugely confused by the message-body in GET requests with a message-body but neither Content-Length nor Transfer-Encoding, and Wireshark following section 4.3 might make it clearer that the server isn't recognizing the message-body.

Comment: "Content-Type" can not determine whether the TCP have a message body, but why Wireshark still wait for the end of the body? I am still confused about this. How I can get the right display on wireshark? Remove the content-type or add an content-lenght:0 header?

Comment: You can try a different HTTP client (e.g. Chrome). And you can also analyze HTTP traffic in a form of text stream by applying "Follow TCP stream".

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your capture is missing a packet - for example, because, for some reason, the program that captured the trace didn't happen to capture that packet.

Frame 747 is a packet from the initiator of the conversation (the HTTP client, i.e. the browser or...) that's part of a request (presumably a request, as it's coming from the initiator of the connection) that didn't fit in a single link-layer packet.

Wireshark reports it as "TCP segment of a reassembled PDU" because it didn't find *all* of the packets containing the request, and couldn't reassemble it (yes, that's not the best phrasing, as the PDU *wasn't* reassembled; I'm not sure what a better phrasing would be...).

Wireshark *does*, in some cases, detect "missing" TCP segments, by noticing "holes" in the TCP sequence number space.  What are the TCP sequence numbers, segment length, and "next sequence number" values in your capture for frames 746, 747, and 750?

Comment: I captured several times, every time I got the same result. So weird.  I found that TCP 744[SYN WS=64], TCP 745[SYN,ACK WS: NOT SET], Why TCP 746[ACK] still use WS=64?

Comment: Please file a bug on the Wireshark Bugzilla, as per my comment on Den's answer.

Comment: Can you share the dump? It's not enough data.

Comment: @Den, I attached the dump on the bug,https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11104

Comment: @Field.wei I've updated my answer according with the data from the dump